# Angular 8 Material - Customize select option style to fit your needs

Tags: css, angular-material

I have an element of select options, each option have two texts, card number and a label that shows your card balance, i want to float them in one line with a space between, like this image:

[image]

I've tried **display flex** but it didn't take any effect.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <select matNativeControl required>
        <option value="default">Select your card</option>
        <option value="card_number">
            1234 4567 8901 2345
            <span class="label">1,200000$</span>
        </option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [**Basic mat-select**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>
        <div> 4567 8901 2345</div>
        <div class="label">1,200000$</div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-option-text{
  display: flex!important;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
```

[See stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecpvfe?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

Note! 
I guess you can not deal with the selected value

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: the main problem now is, when you select the option it shows without **<div>** tag, it wraps all texts inside span tag like this one here:
`<span class="ng-tns-c17-4 ng-star-inserted">4567 8901 2345
 1,200000$</span>`